# iphone UITesting a button that is a number

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, instruments, cs193p, ui-testing

I'm trying out UITesting for the iPhone, and I thought I would use the simple rpn calculator from the lecture 2 of stanford's cs193p iTunes U class to run my first tests on.

my javascript is as follows

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["3"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Enter"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["4"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["/"].tap();

var display = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().staticTexts()[1].value();
if (display == "0.75") {
    UIALogger.logPass("3 E 4 /");
} else {
    UIALogger.logFail("3 E 4 /");
}
```

However the script runs sin enter cos /
In the editor log it is showing

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[3].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Enter"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[4].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["/"].tap();
```

So somehow instruments is converting my string "3" into the index 3 and then tapping the third button.

So I could call the buttons by their index number, but I would much prefer to call them by their text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation with using brackets to access UIAElementArray's that numbers get treated as an indices. 8-(.

Instead just add `firstWithName()`:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons().firstWithName("3").tap();
```

See [UIAElementArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementArrayClassReference/Introduction/Introduction.html)